# How to use SNMP for collecting data from other machines?

Tags: c#, snmp

Consider a LAN network in any organization. In one machine we will be installing an application that collects system audit data. If Active Directory feature is enabled, it can collect details from AD user machines also. But, how to collect machine information like WMI from other systems in a network if Active Directory feature is not there? When i researched in google, found SNMP will be useful.

Can anybody help me here with what actually I have to do here? Not the coding.
What are steps for retrieving details from SNMP?
I have got some client libraries like SnmpSharpLib etc. but executing the samples generating error.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: WMI does not require a domain/AD to function, local account/permissions can be used.

Comment: @AlexK.: You saying i can retrieve other machine details using WMI. What permissions should be set in other machines?

Comment: It needs to be a local admin, see the comments in the answer here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/30273791-1952-4315-a5c3-7d809f9724c1/can-you-connect-to-wmi-remotely-using-a-local-user-account?forum=winserverManagement

Comment: @AlexK. : That worked like charm. But it is not working for Win7, Win8 Machines. I am trying to access from a Win10 Machine. Among Win10 machine it is working properly. any guess?

Answer (score 3):

SNMP is a server/client based protocol. There are two options here:

1. Either the other systems in the network act as clients that send SNMP traps with relevant data to the system that collects data, which acts as a server.
2. Or the other systems in the network act as servers, from which the system that collects data can get data by sending SNMP requests, hence acting as a client.

Option 1 is easier if new systems, that are added to the network, which also need monitoring.
Option 2 allows more control over what data you wish to collect. If you suddenly feel you require other types of data, you can just have the server request these, rather than reconfigure all the other systems to send traps for the specific type of data.

Etiher way the other systems are going to require some type of SNMP daemon or client running and so will the server.

Comment: van Ingen: What all are the configuration changes required for machines to work as a client or as a server?

Comment: csLijo: I have to admit that my knowledge of SNMP is limited to basic protocol understanding and SNMP traffic between a daemon and network hardware.

If I were in you shoes I would pick one of the options I outlined earlier, based on what works best for you. Then I would try and use something off the shelf; either in you preferred language (C# is not my forte; to put it mildly) or even a complete (OSS) solution.